# How to use OrderedMapIterator.previous()

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons-collection

Using Apache Commons Collections I found the `OrderedMapIterator` interface to navigate back and forth in `OrderedMap`. Iterating to the next entry works as expected. Going to the previous element doesn't return the previous element but the current element instead.

```
OrderedMap<String, String> linkedMap = new LinkedMap<>();
linkedMap.put("key 1", "value 1");
linkedMap.put("key 2", "value 2");
linkedMap.put("key 3", "value 3");

OrderedMapIterator<String, String> iterator = linkedMap.mapIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(key);

    if (key.endsWith("2") && iterator.hasPrevious()) {
        System.out.println("previous: " + iterator.previous());
        iterator.next(); // back to current element
    }
}
```

I expected the output

```
key 1
key 2
previous: key 1
key 3
```

but got

```
key 1
key 2
previous: key 2
key 3
```

Do I use `OrderedMapIterator` wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because technically `.previous()` does  not exactly set current entry to previous, but to `next.before`. Look how iteration process works:

```
nextEntry() {
    ...
    last = next; //its current
    next = next.after;
    ...

previousEntry() {
    ...
    final LinkEntry<K, V> previous = next.before;
    ...
    next = previous;
    last = previous;
```

So your flow will affect the `last(current)`|`next` states as follows:

```
null|1 -> (next) -> 1|2 -> (next) -> 2|3 <- (previous?) <- 2|2 -> (next) -> 3|null
```

The reason i may think why is behaves so, because its intended to call `.next()`, `.previous()` in separate loops.

Imagine a situation where you iterate all way forward, and then need to iterate all way back.

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String key = it.next();
    list.add(key);
}
while (it.hasPrevious()) {
    String key = it.previous();
    list.remove(key);
}
```

With the behaviour which you want to have, you would ended up with [key 3] in list, which is not correct, but currently it works fine.

Comment: Iterating to `next` and `previous` in separate loops sounds like a good reason.